# How can I add a link to the parent category on single product pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and adding a custom field value to the single product page with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_field',6 );
function custom_field() {
global $product; 
$field = $product->get_meta( 'my_field' );
$field2 = $product->get_meta( 'my_field2' );

if ( ! empty($my_field) ) {
    echo '<div>Text: ' . $my_field2 . ' <br> Text 2: ' . $my_field . ' </div>';
}

else{
  echo '<div> Text: ' . $my_field2 . ' </div>';
}
}
```

I need to add a link to the value of the field my_field2, and the link should refer to the main parent category of the product (so not the immediate parent category since there sometimes are several parent categories, but the main ome that does not have any parents and is highest in hierarchy). How can I achieve this?

See above code, this is my current function.